# How to get the order information inside the customer creation hook?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

When a visitor buys a new product in my WooCommerce shop, I'm using the `woocommerce_created_customer` hook to create a new user on an external database with some information I get from the `$customer_id, $new_customer_data, $password_generated` arguments.

For example:

```
function action_woocommerce_created_customer($customer_id, $new_customer_data, $password_generated) {
    // Create a new user on external database
}
add_action('woocommerce_created_customer', 'action_woocommerce_created_customer', 10, 3);
```

Well. What I need is a connection to the current order to get the order id. In my shop, a user account can only be created in combination with an order. Is there a way to get order information inside the `woocommerce_created_customer` hook? Or is this `do_action` just called before the order is done?

I thought about using another hook after the payment is done. But this is not possible in my case because this is the only hook I found which I can get the unhashed user password, which I very need.

Do you have an idea how to get the order information inside the customer creation hook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order is created after the customer.

```
$this->process_customer( $posted_data );
$order_id = $this->create_order( $posted_data );
$order    = wc_get_order( $order_id );
```

Use this hook to do the stuff.

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', $order_id, $posted_data, $order );
```

`$posted_data` contains the username and password

```
$username    = ! empty( $posted_data['account_username'] ) ? $posted_data['account_username'] : '';
$password    = ! empty( $posted_data['account_password'] ) ? $posted_data['account_password'] : '';
```

Comment: Thank you. But I guess that there I only have access to the hashed password. I need the unhashed, original password to create an parallel account on another application. Or is the password still unhashed in `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed `?

Comment: Yes. It's unhshed